# Using Contains for objects in List collection

Tags: java, list, collections, contains

I'm trying to find an object in the List collection by his name using Contains method, but, somehow, it doesn't work. How should I use it?

**This is how I try to use this**

```
CandyDao.getAllCandys().contains("Caramel")
```

But it can't find an object which I need.

**CandyDao.java**

```
public class CandyDao {
  private List<Candy> candys = Arrays.asList(new Candy("Caramel", 3, false),
          new Candy("Marmelade", 2, true));

  public List<Candy> getAllCandys(){
    return candys;
  }
}
```

**Candy.java**

```
  public class Candy {
  private String name;
  private float price;
  private boolean InStock;

  public Candy() {
  }

  public Candy(String name, float price, boolean InStock) {
    setName(name);
    setPrice(price);
    setInStock(InStock);
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public float getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public void setPrice(float price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  public boolean getInStock() {
    return InStock;
  }

  public void setInStock(boolean InStock) {
    this.InStock = InStock;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the list contains `Candy` objects, the `contains()` method needs a `Candy` object for the comparison, so you can't use `contains("Caramel")`.

To check if the list contains a `Candy` object with a `name` of `"Caramel"`, you can use Java 8+ Streams to do the search:

```
CandyDao.getAllCandys().stream().Map(Candy::getName).anyMatch("Caramel"::equals);
```

The equivalent non-stream version would be:

```
boolean hasCaramel = false;
for (Candy candy : CandyDao.getAllCandys()) {
    if ("Caramel".equals(candy.getName())) {
        hasCaramel = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override the `equals` & `hashcode` method like below :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Candy candy = (Candy) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, candy.name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name);
}
```

Now, Since the equals function only checks name for equality of `Candy` object, the following should work:

```
CandyDao.getAllCandys().contains(new Candy("Caramel", 0, true)) .   //2nd & 3rd arg of Candy constructor are inessential/dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `Object#equals` method in `Candy` as shown below:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Candy)) {
        return false;
    }

    Candy that = (Candy) o;

    return Objects.equals(that.getName(), this.getName());
}
```

After overriding, `List#contains` should return `true` if the name matches.

Comment: That still won't make `candy.equals("Caramel")` return true.

Comment: Agreed, he should be using candy object with name "Caramel", instead of using String.

Comment: Like [answer by Pankaj Singhal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52803992/5221149) shows.

Answer (score 0):

`getAllCandys()` method returns a list of `Candy`objects. You should look each element's `name`property on the list. So `c`is an element of `candys`list. Use `c.getName().contains("Caramel")` to look for `"Caramel"`

```
for(Candy c : candys) {
            System.out.println(c.getName() + " contains? " + c.getName().contains("Caramel"));
        }
```

Comment: `list.contains("Caramel")` is a search of the list for a object that is *equal* to argument, i.e. `c.getName().equals("Caramel")`, not `c.getName().contains("Caramel")`.

Comment: Yes, you're right and i also know the difference. But I misunderstood the question.